# Is there another way to add a real-time update for your django app

Tags: python, django, websocket, pusher, django-channels

I just have two questions:

- is there another way to add a real-time update for your django app rather than using Django channels? please if there is another way let me know because django channels requires a lot of changes on the server settings and it's just a pain on the ass to implement them.
- I once used Pusher instead of django channels and websockets It just worked well on my app and i didn't have to install django channels and my app worked just fine on WSGI mode? I'm really confused how this was even possible if any one here is an expert on the subject can you please explain how Pusher works and why we need Django channels in the first place since as far as i can see implementing pusher with django is so much easier than using django channels.

Thanks in advance

Comment: you could just call an endpoint repeatedly checking for messages if thats real time enough for you ... but channels isnt really all that hard ...

Comment: thanks bro i just hate when i have to change my app  to an ASGI mode and some servers doasn't support that. have you ever worked with Pusher https://pusher.com/ before?